# Change our atomic habits to attain changes in our life

Tags: meditation, self

Atomic habits those are pour in our life and we could not focus on them and we get fall apart in life, So what are the various ways to focus on our atomic habits to make sustainable change or make our self better.

Comment: do you mean patterns? i think u mean patterns, like when a moment of compassion or pity followed by a moment of lust or passion?